# Unable to access stylesheets in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to the CodeIgniter, however when i try to link bootstrap files to my project blank(white) screen appears.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");?>" >
```

I put all bootstrap files inside assets folder which is in the same level as root directories as follows

> - **application**
> - **assets**
>
>   - **css**
>
>     - **bootstrap.min.css**
> - **system**

I tried alternative such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

And

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo link_tag("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css")?>" >
```

none of these seems to work, what should i do? someone help me please!

Comment: Please post the view code which you are loading from your controller. would be better if you post your controller code as well.

Comment: Have you set your base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';` In Ci3 versions and up it is a must if your url has ip address in it the links will not work properly because you have not set base url

Comment: Check the link in the source code. What you get there? is it showing the correct url? And also check the part mention by @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a file in the view folder (application/views) called home_view.php and another file in css folder(application/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css).
In order to link your css file into the view you need to add this line in your home_view.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

If your assets folder is in the same level directory as application folder you can make a constant in constants.php(application/config/constants.php) file:

```
define('MY_ASSETS', 'assets/');
```

and your link will be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo MY_ASSETS; ?>css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Comment: i did that too,but only blank screen appears without any errror messages. i have header.php inside view/template folder i put the link there and css are inside assets as described above, i don't get it what seems to be a problem.

Comment: have you load the header.php in your home_view.php?

Comment: when i follow latter method you mentioned, pages load but doesn't take bootstrap styles.

Comment: Set your base url in the config.php..you can make an inspect to see where it links the file...

Comment: my base url  is **$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/testapp/';**  in config.php where testapp is my projects name, when i inspect there is no link inside head  tag. should i do some changes in my index.php file

Comment: that double semicolon was just typo in the comment by the way.

Comment: it worked when i added  `$this->load->helper('url');` inside controllers/class/methods.

Comment: i didnt knew that you haven't already added..it was necessary for sure but i suppose that you already did that.. :)